# Is it possible to access inline styles in a structured way using cheerio?

Tags: cheerio

I have an element:

`<svg style="width:100%;height:100%;">`

I know that I can read the styles using cheerio in some way similar to:

`const hasWidth = $el([style*="height"])`

But I would need to do a lot of extra work to reliably parse CSS values from the style attribute.

Is there a more structured way to access styles of an element using cheerio?

Comment: There isn't, but with a browser you can do things like document.getComputedStyle()

Comment: There is also jsdom if one needs to do this in NodeJS, which has implemented the style property. But it is missing other web apis like getBBox() and probably getComputedStyle()